# How to cast my templated inherited classes in C#?

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance

I have a class `A` which inherited from a templated class : `M<C, D>` and a class `C : T<D>`
In execution `A` is a class typed `M<C, D>` but is not a class typed `M<T<D>,D>` and I didn't understand why. There is a way to have this correspondence?

I use LTS Unity 2017.4.

```cs
public class ContentItemModule<C,D> where C : ContentItem<D> where D : A_Data { }

public class ImplementedContentItemModule : ContentItemModule<ImplementedContentItem , ImplementedData> { }
```

```cs
public class ContentItem<D> where D : A_Data { }

public class ImplementedContentItem : ContentItem<ImplementedData> { 

    ImplementedContentItemModule _contentItemModule;

    public void Init() {
         Console.Log(_contentItemModule is ImplementedContentItemModule); // print True
         Console.Log(_contentItemModule is ContentItemModule<ImplementedContentItem, ImplementedData>); // print True
         Console.Log(_contentItemModule is ContentItemModule<ContentItem<ImplementedData>, ImplementedData>); // print False, WHY ?
    }
}
```

I expect the third log returns True but it returns False.

*Note: For one ImplementedData there is only one ImplementedContentItem.*

Is there a keyword which can help me (or another way) or it's not possible to know if my _contentItemModule is a ContentItemModule, ImplementedData>?

Comment: You can do this with generic interfaces, but not with generic classes. You might want to read up about covariance and contravariance (see, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @Iridium I didn't know this, thanks! I will read your link but I think that replacing my classes by interfaces requires a too big rework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that generics don't follow the same assignability rules as normal classes. For a generic class to be assignable, the types must match exactly. Here's an example to show you why:

Assuming we have:

```
class A { }
class B: A { }
```

polymorphism says we can assign instances of B to variable of type A. This is because a B **is an** A. Now consider a list:

```
var a_s = new List<A>();
a_s.Add(new A());
var b_s = (List<B>)a_s;
var b = b_s[0]; // But b_s[0] is the same as a_s[0], which is an A instance, and A's can't be assigned to B's!! What happened?!
```

This is why generic classes must match exactly. More specialized inputs are fine, since they can automatically be *up*cast to the appropriate type. However, More specialized outputs are not - you can't *down*cast carelessly, which is what happens in the (hypothetical) code above. This is apparent in languages that have different upcast and downcast syntax, such as C++'s `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` and F#'s `:>` and `:?>`.

This distinction between input and output types is actually important, and is formalized in C# as `in` and `out` generic parameters, corresponding to the concepts of covariance and contravariance. This only applies to interfaces though.

Given that polymorphic behavior of generic arguments is logically impossible, you're probably making a subtle mistake in your design and would run into it even if you refactored to use interfaces. Analyze your design carefully, and move polymorphic logic away from generics. You *can* use reflection to work around this limitation, but you really shouldn't, unless you have a very very good reason.

Comment: Okay it's clearer now.
So if I want doing something like it I have to use Interface. Or a "bad" way because it's not logical.
Thank you for this note; I will rethink my code.